# Print a sequence (unicode)-subscript in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to create a string like...

```
mystring = "X\u2080 + X\u2081 + X\u2082 + X\u2083 + ..."
print(mystring)
```

Which should output **`'X₀ + X₁ + X₂ + X₃ + ...'`**

However, I want to add them sequentially with a loop.

I have tried:

```
mystring = ""
for i in range(0,4):
   mystring += f"X\u208{str(i)} +"
```

But I get the error

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-5
truncated \uXXXX escape
```

What is the correct way of adding print terms with unicode sequentially in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences must be completely specified and can't be combined with placeholders in an f-string literal.

To generate unicode characters programatically, you can use the `chr` function instead:

```
mystring = ' + '.join(f"X{chr(0x2080 + i)}" for i in range(4))
```

`mystring` becomes:

```
X₀ + X₁ + X₂ + X₃
```

Comment: I just realized that `0x2080 + i` is only valid for values `range(0,10)`. Do you know how I could make subscript `10, 11, 12, ...`?

Comment: There are no unicode subscript numerals beyond 9, so you would have to switch your approach to, for example, certain formatting languages such as HTML, LaTeX, MathML, etc.